# How is Canadian capital gains tax calculated when I trade exclusively in USD?

Tags: canada, capital-gains-tax, canada-revenue-agency

99% of my entire net worth is denominated in USD, and I only trade in USD stocks & bonds.

Does Canadian capital gains tax only trigger when I attempt to convert those gains/losses into CAD? In other words, can I continue trading indefinitely, year after year, solely in USD without concern for the CRA, and only when I try to convert it into CAD will the capital gains trigger for that particular year?

Can anyone shed some light on how much I am supposed to pay the CRA?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't matter what currency you trade in or barter, if you liquidated a position - you recognize the gain. See [the CRA guidance here](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/forms-publications/publications/t4037/capital-gains.html#P279_29831). To handle USD transactions, use [this CRA guidance on currency conversions](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/forms-publications/publications/t4037/capital-gains.html#P317_34283).