# Are everyday foreign currency exchange fees deductible with the CRA as a capital loss?

Tags: canada, foreign-exchange, capital-gain, capital-loss

Let's say today's official market exchange rate from USD to CAD is 1.30.

However, my bank or Western Union is only willing to offer me a rate of 1.20. Therefore, I end up converting $100K USD to just $120K CAD. Can I deduct the loss I suffered from the difference in "actual transactional rate" with the "official market rate" as a capital loss (i.e., -$10K CAD)?

Comment: @littleadv I'm not trading stocks this time; I'm simply converting it through a business service.

Comment: Also discussed [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/157138/how-is-canadian-capital-gains-tax-calculated-when-i-trade-exclusively-in-usd). You keep asking the same questions again and again. Are you reading the answers?

Comment: It doesn't matter. You have your basis in CAD and you have your result in CAD. If it was an investment then the difference is capital gain/loss. If it's your living expenses then it's not deductible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot claim "hypothetical" losses. I.e.: "I could have gotten X, but I only got Y, so X-Y is my loss" - no, you cannot do that. You could have gotten Y because that's exactly what you've got.

If you bought $100CAD worth of USD and then sold that USD for $99CAD - you have $1CAD loss. If you sold that USD for $101CAD - you have $1CAD gain. What the "official" rate was doesn't matter, what matters is how much you've got.

You're confusing this with your scenarios of trading US stocks, where you need to convert transaction values into CAD if you get to keep USD, but that's basically splitting your trade into two steps: step 1 - sell shares, get CAD; step 2 - buy USD with that CAD. You use the same USD/CAD rate for both the steps, and that's where the "official" rate comes into play.

Comment: Why is this considered a hypothetical loss? It's different from the official rate. The official rate is what cost basis and other transactions are based off of. So why not this one too?

Comment: @AlanSTACK not sure I'm following your logic. When you bought your USD you've established basis in CAD. When you sold your USD you've established gain/loss in CAD. That's what matters. What exactly is your concern? If you sold your USD at a rate which differs *significantly* from the official, you may run into some questions as to why, but as long as it is within the variance of banks' markups and fees, it doesn't matter. $1.30 vs $1.20 is a big difference, so you may need to explain your loss if audited as it may be an unreasonable decision on your part.

Comment: Oh okay, we are on the same page then. I got confused by your last paragraph. Not sure what you mean't there.

Comment: @AlanSTACK what I meant is that the "official" rate is the one that you use when you don't actually make any de-facto conversions (like when you trade a US stock and keep the USD, but you end up recognizing gain on the stock trade and establishing basis in the resulting USD)

Comment: Oh, okay, got it. Basically, the official rate only matters in "pretend conversions." When I make actual "real conversions," I don't have to consider the official rate at all; I just need to look at what I paid versus what I received.